# Is there any collocation?

Tags: collocations

> Every day Kino went out to sea to look for the pearl.

In this sentence, is there any collocation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a task from a textbook? I'd say that "every day" is a collocation, but I'm not sure what counts as (for?) one. "Went out to sea" also looks like one.

Comment: Without contexts, can we say that this sentence is grammatically correct? Thanks again.

Comment: I'll take the fifth on that, 'cause I'm not so sure about "out to sea". It might mean something idiomatic, like "go sailing", instead of just "go to the shore and look for the pearl there". If "out to sea" is okay, I'd say the sentence is okay.

Comment: "Without contexts" -- what does that mean?  That we should not assume a prior context? Or that we should not allow the sentence to establish its own implicit prior context?  If so, "*the* pearl" is ungrammatical. It should be "*a* pearl".  *Went out to sea* is ok.

Comment: Oh hey, I know this story. Steinbeck, I think? Yes, it's specifically about a certain pearl. And out to sea is definitely a good phrase.

Answer (score 2):

**every day** and **out to sea** are two collocations since the words in those phrases are often found together